# TensorFlow - Difference between tf.VariableScope and tf.variable_scope

Tags: python, tensorflow, contextmanager

Have found two links on TensorFlow website referring to `variable scope`, one is [tf.variable_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope) which is the one most commonly used, and the other [tf.VaribleScope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/VariableScope).

As there's no example for the application of `tf.VariableScope`, just reading through the document, I couldn't distinguish whether there's a difference between the two. Tried to implement by replacing  `tf.variable_scope` with `tf.VariableScope` but got the following error (which indicates there're some differences)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/NER/window_model.py", line 105, in <module>
    model = NaiveNERModel(embeddings)
  File "/home/NER/window_model.py", line 64, in __init__
    pred = self.add_prediction_op(embed)
  File "/home/NER/window_model.py", line 82, in add_prediction_op
    with tf.VariableScope('Layer1', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()):
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Snippet of the original workable code

```py
with tf.variable_scope('Layer1', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()):
        W = tf.get_variable("W", [self.dim * self.window_size, self.dim * self.window_size])
        b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", [self.dim * self.window_size])
        h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(embed, W) + b1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.VariableScope`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/VariableScope) is an actual scope class that holds the `name`, `initializer`, `regularizer`, `partitioner`, and many other properties that are propagated to the variables defined in that scope. This class is more of a collection of properties and not a context manager, so you can't use it in `with` statement (that's what the error tells you).

Since the scope has to be first pushed on top of the stack (tensorflow internal class `_VariableStore` is responsible for this), then popped back from the stack, manual instantiation of `tf.VariableScope` is tedious and error-prone. That's where the context manager comes in.

[`tf.variable_scope`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope) is a context manager that makes it easier to work with variable scopes. As the documentation describes it:

> A context manager for defining ops that creates variables (layers).
>
> This context manager validates that the (optional) values are from the same graph, ensures that graph is the default graph, and pushes a name scope and a variable scope.

The actual work with variables is delegated to the `tf.VariableScope` object that is created under the hood.